# JSF Select Menu, handle removed values

Tags: jsf-2.2, selectonemenu

In our application we have various select fields. The content of the select fields is always filled with values from the database, for example a `currency` selector will contain the currencies added in the database, or `User` Objects might be choosen depending of the role of certain users.

Now, the problem is that this data might change over time, but *old* instances using this values should remain untouched. If a user has now been picket as `leadDeveloper`, because of his roles, but he left the company, the select-list does no longer contain that user, hence the select field will now show the no-select option, because the list source does not contain the element anymore.

Is there a nice way, to bypass this problem?

concrete example:

java:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{

  public List<IKeyValuePair> getAvailableDeveloper(){
      // everything available to select-fields is implementing
      // iKeyValuePair, most the time used as id/name, depending on entity
      return userDataService.getUsersWithRole("developer");
  } 
}

public class User implements IKeyValuePair{

    //properties

    @Override
    public string getKey(){
       //use id
       return this.id.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public string getValue(){
       //use lastname, firstname
       return this.lastname + ", " + this.firstname;
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{project.leadDeveloper}" style="width:125px" readonly="#{project.closed}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.availableDevelopers}" var="dev" 
          itemLabel="#{dev.getValue()}" itemValue="#{dev.getKey()}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now, a user would be choosen from that list - let's say **alice**. From now on the historic view of that project will show **alice** as selected developer in the disabled selectOneMenu, once the project has ended.

2 years later, alice left the company, therefore her role **developer** has been revoked. `getAvailableDeveloper()` will no longer contain `alice`, and so the selected value is no longer part of the data-source - the select field now will show **Select One**.

I could manually ensure that the user in question is added to the list for history purposes (if missing) - however that would be something I need to implement *case-by-case* in the respective getter-method, depending on the entity type.

It would be nicer if this could be handled in an automatic way inside a (custom) renderer of the selectOneMenu. But before I go down that way, I wanted to ask if there are best-practice-solutions on this topic.

ps.: Code is no exact copy, just a quick example to outline the problem.

Comment: At first glance, this looks like something you should be handling in your data layer, where you should be retiring your entities and the entire tree of dependent entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by calling each individual `getter` through a proxy-method, which takes care of the remaining work.

Instead of

```
public List<IKeyValuePair> getAvailableDeveloper(){
  // everything available to select-fields is implementing
  // iKeyValuePair, most the time used as id/name, depending on entity
  return userDataService.getUsersWithRole("developer");
}
```

along with the markup

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.availableDevelopers}" var="dev" 
      itemLabel="#{dev.getValue()}" itemValue="#{dev.getKey()}" />
```

I ended up to call a "generic" method, passing the current selection and actual List and finally adding this selection to the returned list, if not existing:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.proxyForLists(myBean.availableDevelopers, currentElement)}" var="dev" 
      itemLabel="#{dev.getValue()}" itemValue="#{dev.getKey()}" />
```

and the proxy method

```
 public List<IKeyValuePair> proxyForLists(List<IKeyValuePair> source, Object selection){

   if (selection == null) return source;

   if (selection instanceof User){
       User selectedUser = (User) selection;
       KeyValuePair kvp = new KeyValuePair(selectedUser.getShortName(), selectedUser);
       if (!source.contains(kvp)){
          source.add(kvp);
       }
    }
    //other types handled as well. 
    return source;
 }
```

So, whenever a selected Value `A` is no longer part of the source list, it is added by the proxy method, making the select Field able to show it again. For "new" creations, `A` is no longer part of the source list, hence a user can no longer select `A`.